# CSS is transitioning when it should not

Tags: css, reactjs

I can't figure out how to solve the problem with "jumping" navbar.
When I resize browser window, the navbar plays transition animation.
So here is codesandbox to understand better what I mean.
Try to resize the window.
https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-problem-3jf9cb

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you state how your navbar should be after resizing?

Comment: That is happening because you've set a transition on your `.navigation-menu` at `@media (max-width: 756px)`. so it transitions both when it appears and disappears. You will have to not allow transition on hide.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJ4oHe7973AhWdQUEAHdyDDLgQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F38526764%2Fdisable-css-transitions-on-window-resize&usg=AOvVaw2Z_8X1RiTUtStvoz9QZlRC

Comment: @MosiaThabo Well, yes. But is there a way to solve this with just CSS ?

Comment: If I was you, I wouldn't worry about it. why? because users won't be resizing their pages like you do as the developer. If there's any, they'll be few. `@media` just helps accommodate different screen sizes. Say for example, someone who views your site from a mobile app... your app will load to that screen size and that effect will not be visible. And the same can be said for users with different devices.

Comment: The one way I think can be done is to disable the transition... and you can't do that with css during `resize` event. JS is your only option.

Comment: @MosiaThabo Thank you for you answers! Well, yeah if I open this page on mobile I won't be able to play with window size. But I am on PC and I am still learning and playing with windows resize. So and when I see this weird stuff happening I am curios why is it happening and how to get rid of this problem. But you are 100% right. I should not worry about it. Thanks again for your time! :)